# Passar variável jquery para buscar subcategoria

Tags: php

Estou fazendo dois select, o de categoria e subcategoria. Ambos via MySQL. Gostaria que ao selecionar a categoria, seja passado o ID da categoria para a Subcategoria.

```
$rsCategoria    = $conexao->query("SELECT * FROM categoria WHERE idioma = 'pt-br' ");
$rsSubcategoria = $conexao->query("SELECT * FROM categoriasub WHERE id_categoria = '{$id_categoria}' AND idioma = 'pt-br' ");
```

.

```
<select id="categoria" name="categoria" class="input form-control col-lg-10" required>
                        <option value="" selected="selected">Selecione</option>
                        <?php while ($rowCategoria = $rsCategoria->fetch_assoc()) {?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $rowCategoria['ID_Categoria'] ?>"><?php echo $rowCategoria['nome'] ?></option>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </select>

                    <select id="subcategoria" name="subcategoria" class="input form-control col-lg-10" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                        <option value="" selected="selected">Selecione</option>
                        <?php while ($rowSubcategoria = $rsSubcategoria->fetch_assoc()) {?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $rowSubcategoria['ID_Categoria'] ?>"><?php echo $rowSubcategoria['nome'] ?></option>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </select>
```

Qual seria a melhor forma de buscar o a subcategoria?

Comment: Costumo usar requisicão ajax colocando um evento onchange no primeiro <select> enviando o código da categoria e a resposta da requisição preenche o <select> da subcategoria

Comment: @WagnerSoares Como montaria o while usando o AJAX?

Comment: Está a tentar atualizar a subcategoria automaticamente quando o utilizador escolhe a categoria é isso?

Comment: @Isac Exatamente. Após selecione uma categoria, seja carregado as subcategorias.

Comment: A melhor opção será exatamente o que o WagnerSoares indicou por *Ajax* para não atualizar a página toda, e colocar o resultado diretamente no `<select>` caso seja html ou construir o `<select>` com base num *json* de resposta.

Comment: @Isac Como montaria o while usando o AJAX ou JSON?

Answer (score 1):

Consegui fazer, vou deixar registrado aqui para quem tiver as mesmas dúvidas que eu.

**SELECT**

```
$rsCategoria    = $conexao->query("SELECT * FROM categoria");
```

**HTML**

```
<select id="categoria" name="categoria" required>
    <option value="" selected="selected">Selecione</option>
        <?php while ($rowCategoria = $rsCategoria->fetch_assoc()) {?>
            <option value="<?php echo $rowCategoria['ID_Categoria'] ?>"><?php echo $rowCategoria['nome'] ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
</select>

<select id="subcategoria" name="subcategoria" required>
    <option>Selecione acima primeiro</option>
</select>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("select[name=categoria]").change(function(){
        $("select[name=subcategoria]").html('<option value="">Carregando...</option>');

        $.post("inc_subCategoria.php",
            {ID_Categoria:$(this).val()},
            function(valor){
                $("select[name=subcategoria]").html(valor);
           }
        )
    })
});
```

**inc_subCategoria.php**

```
<?php
include 'conexao.php';

$rs = $conexao->query("SELECT * FROM categoriasub WHERE id_categoria = '{$_POST['ID_Categoria']}' AND idioma = 'pt-br' ");

    echo '<option value="" selected="selected">Selecione</option>';
while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<option value="'.$row['ID_Subcategoria'].'">'.$row['nome'].'</option>';
}
```

Espero que isso possa ajudar alguém. Se ajudou marque para cima.